# Kafka Stream custom join using state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need a special join and I've follow this [examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.1.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/CustomStreamTableJoinIntegrationTest.java).
Why I need a custom join ? I need a [KStream > KTable join](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join) and the default will create an intermediate topic and reorder the data incoming from the based topic and duplicate events, seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276161/1590168). The events are the same but I need to be sure an event is processed **ONE** and **ONLY** time. During the join, the event (with the same value) seems to be reproduced during the join phase.

I like the idea to fetch another store in order to get complete the current event (add some data). With this, I'm sure the the event will be used 1 time only.
I've extract the whole code in order to test it with `TopologyTestDriver [here](https://gist.github.com/tchiotludo/edaecf291931338c0e76307ac63d5232).

I tested this and the current one is sending this error :

> Table data unavailable for key bobby, sending the join result as null

If I send before to KTable, the join is correct :

> Table data available for key alice, sending fully populated join message KeyValue(alice, (666.66, 8))

So I don't really understand how this example works.
I've reproduced on my side and I [have the same issue](https://github.com/kestra-io/kestra/blob/fix/kafka-executor-refactor-custom-join/runner-kafka/src/main/java/io/kestra/runner/kafka/streams/ExecutorWorkerStateResultJoiner.java), the KTable update won't be trigger on the join on the `Transformer`.

```java
    private KStream<String, Executor> joinWorkerResult(KTable<String, WorkerTaskResultTransformer.WorkerTaskResultState> workerTaskResultKTable, KStream<String, Executor> executionKTable) {
        return executionKTable
            .transformValues(
                () -> new ExecutorWorkerStateResultJoiner(workerTaskResultKTable.queryableStoreName(), this.metricRegistry),
                Named.as("joinWorkerResult.join"),
                workerTaskResultKTable.queryableStoreName()
            );
    }
```

I have the feeling that it's normal, the StateStore from the Ktable is not linked in the underlying topology, it's **only** linked to the `Transformer` to be queried, but update on the KTable is not send to this `Transformer`

On Kafka Stream based implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/bf359f8e2924ee03b34a6f7e7eaf80bef55f9d98/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImpl.java#L1241), there is a direct connection `builder.addGraphNode(graphNode, streamTableJoinNode);` that this example don't have.

So the question:

- is this example is working ?
- is there a way to do a custom join with Kafka Stream DSL ?