# Kafka streams join duplicates

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, kafka-join

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate of [kafka-streams join produce duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273180/kafka-streams-join-produce-duplicates). I think my scenario is different. I'm also already using kafka EOS via `processing.guarantee=exactly_once`

I  have an input topic `transactions_topic` with json data that looks like

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-08T13:04:30Z",
    "transactionId": "842d38ea-1d3d-41a4-b724-bcc7e81aec9a",
    "accountId": "account123",
    "amount": 1.0
}
```

It's represented as a simple class using lombok `@Data`

```java
@Data
class Transaction {
    String transactionId;
    String timestamp;
    String accountId;
    Double amount;
}
```

I want to compute the total amount spent by accountId for the past 1 hour, past 1 day and past 30 days. These computations are the features represented by the the following class

```java
@Data
public class Features {
    double totalAmount1Hour;
    double totalAmount1Day;
    double totalAmount30Day;
}
```

I'm using kafka-streams and springboot to achieve this.
First I subscribe to the input topic and select the `accountId` as key

```java
KStream<String, Transaction> kStream = builder.stream(inputTopic,
                        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class)).
                                withTimestampExtractor(new TransactionTimestampExtractor())).
                selectKey((k,v)-> v.getAccountId());
```

`TransactionTimestampExtractor` is implemented as follows

```java
public class TransactionTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {
    @Override
    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord, long l) {
        Transaction value = (Transaction) consumerRecord.value();
        long epoch = Instant.parse(value.getTimestamp()).toEpochMilli();
        return epoch;
    }
}
```

Now in order to compute the total amount for the past 1 hour, past 1 day and past 30 days, I  created a function that will aggregate the amount based on a sliding window

```java
private  <T> KStream<String, T> windowAggregate(KStream<String, Transaction> kStream,
                                                     SlidingWindows window,
                                                     Initializer<T> initializer,
                                                     Aggregator<String, Transaction, T> aggregator,
                                                     Class<T> t) {
        return kStream.
                groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class))).
                windowedBy(window).
                aggregate(initializer,
                        aggregator,
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(t))).
                suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded())).
                toStream().
                map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(k.key(), v));
}
```

Now we can use it like

```java
Aggregator<String, Transaction, Double> amountAggregator = (k, v, aggregate) -> aggregate + v.getAmount();

KStream<String, Double> totalAmount1Hour = windowAggregate(kStream, SlidingWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofHours(1)), () -> 0.0, amountAggregator, Double.class);
       
KStream<String, Double> totalAmount1Day = windowAggregate(kStream, SlidingWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofDays(1)), () -> 0.0, amountAggregator, Double.class);
        
KStream<String, Double> totalAmount30Day = windowAggregate(kStream, SlidingWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofDays(30)), () -> 0.0, amountAggregator, Double.class);
```

Now all I need to do is to join these streams and return a new stream with `Features` as values

```java
private KStream<String, Features> joinAmounts(KStream<String, Double> totalAmount1Hour, KStream<String, Double> totalAmount1Day, KStream<String, Double> totalAmount30Day) {

        JoinWindows joinWindows = JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(0));
        KStream<String, Features> totalAmount1HourAnd1Day = totalAmount1Hour.join(totalAmount1Day,
                (amount1Hour, amount1Day) -> {
                    Features features = new Features();
                    features.setTotalAmount1Hour(amount1Hour);
                    features.setTotalAmount1Day(amount1Day);
                    return features;
                },
                joinWindows,
                StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double(), Serdes.Double()));


        KStream<String, Features> featuresKStream = totalAmount1HourAnd1Day.join(totalAmount30Day,
                (features, amount30Day) -> {
                    features.setTotalAmount30Day(amount30Day);
                    return features;
                },
                joinWindows,
                StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(Features.class), Serdes.Double()));

        return featuresKStream;
    }
```

I print the `features` stream for debugging purposes

```java
KStream<String, Features> features = joinAmounts(totalAmount1Hour, totalAmount1Day, totalAmount30Day);

features.print(Printed.<String, Features>toSysOut().withLabel("features"));
```

This works and prints the correct values for the features however when I process the same payload more than once, the features stream produces duplicates. For example processing the following payload twice produces the following output.

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2022-10-08T01:09:32Z",
    "accountId":"account1",
    "transactionId":"33694a6e-8c15-4cc2-964a-b8b0ecce2682",
    "amount":1.0
}
```

Output

```
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=2.0, totalAmount1Day=1.0, totalAmount30Day=1.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=1.0, totalAmount1Day=2.0, totalAmount30Day=1.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=2.0, totalAmount1Day=2.0, totalAmount30Day=1.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=1.0, totalAmount1Day=1.0, totalAmount30Day=2.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=2.0, totalAmount1Day=1.0, totalAmount30Day=2.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=1.0, totalAmount1Day=2.0, totalAmount30Day=2.0)
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=2.0, totalAmount1Day=2.0, totalAmount30Day=2.0)
```

My expected output would be just the last one

```
[features]: account1, Features(totalAmount1Hour=2.0, totalAmount1Day=2.0, totalAmount30Day=2.0)
```

How can I achive this and get rid of the duplicates in the `features` stream? Is kafka-streams `join()` doing a cartesian product because I have the same timestamp and key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `toStream` will convert from a `KTable` back to a `KStream`, giving you full changelogs for the tables. Then, for every single change of the each of the 3 tables, you will also get a join result.

Maybe a better idea to achieve what you want is to chain your aggregations. So that you generate the `KTable` for 1 hour changes, and from this table you derive the 1 day changes, and from the resulting table you finally generate the 30 day changes. See this Wiki page for an example: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Windowed+aggregations+over+successively+increasing+timed+windows